# Can the filter option in Excel be constantly enabled VB6?

Tags: excel, vb6

I am creating a program in VB6 where data is opened in Excel. I have thousands of lines of data and I use the filter option to view certain data.
What I am wondering is if it is possible to always have the filter option turned on whenever an excel sheet is opened without me having to click filter? I know it's no big deal clicking the filter function but it will be used by others so it would be handy to always have this option in the first row of each column every time a sheet is viewed. I hope this makes sense :/ Thanks

This is my code:

```
Private Sub cmdReports_Click()
Dim ExcelObj As Object
Dim ExcelBook As Object
Dim ExcelSheet As Object
Dim i As Integer


Set ExcelObj = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set ExcelBook = ExcelObj.WorkBooks.Add
Set ExcelSheet = ExcelBook.WorkSheets(1)

With ExcelSheet
.AutoFilterMode = True
For i = 1 To ListView1.ColumnHeaders.Count
.cells(1, i) = ListView1.ColumnHeaders(i).Text
Next i
For i = 1 To ListView1.ListItems.Count
.cells(i + 1, 1) = ListView1.ListItems(i).Text
.cells(i + 1, 2) = ListView1.ListItems(i).SubItems(1)
.cells(i + 1, 3) = ListView1.ListItems(i).SubItems(2)
.cells(i + 1, 4) = ListView1.ListItems(i).SubItems(3)
Next
End With

ExcelObj.Visible = True

Set ExcelSheet = Nothing
Set ExcelBook = Nothing
Set ExcelObj = Nothing
End Sub
```

I tried to add .AutoFilter property to the cells but I get an error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `AutoFilter` with `UsedRange`?

Try this

```
ExcelSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter
```

Comment: Where do I need to put this? I tried it after the With but gave me an error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this line after the last For..Next loop:

```
For i = 1 To ListView1.ColumnHeaders.Count
    .Range(.Cells(1, i), .Cells(ListView1.ListItems.Count + 1, i)).AutoFilter
Next i
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That didn't do anything though unfortunately, just give me the same data without the filter enabled.